# Update null value to a column in dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I need to update a specific set of columns with null value, but when I'm trying to pass null value to dynamic SQL I'm not getting any error or output.

```
DECLARE @Value VARCHAR(100)

SELECT @Value = null
            

DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(1000),@ColumnName VARCHAR(100)

DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Sql= N''

DECLARE UpdatePlantId_Crsr CURSOR

    STATIC FOR          

SELECT ST.name AS TableName,SC.name AS ColumnName 
FROM 
    sys.columns SC
INNER JOIN
    sys.tables ST ON ST.object_Id = SC.Object_Id
WHERE
    SC.name like '%_MLP'
    --AND ST.name not like 'tPlant'
                         
    OPEN UpdatePlantId_Crsr

    IF @@CURSOR_ROWS > 0

    BEGIN

    FETCH NEXT FROM UpdatePlantId_Crsr INTO @TableName,@ColumnName

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

    BEGIN


    SET @Sql= N''
    SELECT @Sql = @Sql + N' UPDATE  '+@TableName +' SET '+@ColumnName+ '= '+ @Value +'  
    '
    PRINT @Sql

        --EXEC(@Sql)

      FETCH NEXT FROM UpdatePlantId_Crsr INTO @TableName,@ColumnName

    END

    END

    CLOSE UpdatePlantId_Crsr

    DEALLOCATE UpdatePlantId_Crsr
```

Comment: . . Your code is clearly SQL Server so I added the tag.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that something is wrong with your application if you need to use dynamic SQL to set tables and columns to `NULL`.  That said, the question can still be answered.

You should use `sp_executesql`.  But given that the table and column names cannot be passed in, just set up the SQL correctly:

```
SET @Sql = N'UPDATE ' + @TableName + ' SET ' + @ColumnName + ' = NULL'  ;

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;  -- yuo can still use it with no parameters
```

I am not sure why you are concatenating the `@sql` string, so I removed that.

Note that `+ NULL` returns `NULL` -- both for string concatenation and addition.